# Symfony2 in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I am trying to configure a **`Symfony 2.3.3`** project into a subdirectory named `dev` to access it like so :

**`www.mydomain.com/dev/`**

Thing is, it is correctly calling the front controller but I get the following error :

> NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /dev/"

Well, I don't like the idea to change all my routes in the `routing.yml` file. So I tried manipulating the `.htaccess` files with `RewriteBase`, but I could not found the solution.
Is there some config to change to Symfony in order to get this to work ?
Do I need to change anything in a `.htaccess` file ?

I use the following `web/.htaccess` file : **[Symfony standard web/.htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess)**

My root `.htaccess` just contains this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can achieve your goal by chaning root .htaccess to redirect any dev/* to dev/web/. But I suggest you other (IMO better way): create a subdomain "dev", and put your dev app to its root directory. You can access then to your dev app like this: dev.mydomain.com

Comment: Actually, it was already a subdomain (I simplified the question). But anyway, I was loosing too much time and I made another distinct subdomain. Thanks for the reply by the bye.